# How do you set bashScriptExtraDefines?

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I have a project which needs to set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include some native shared objects. I believe all that I need to do is ensure that the JVM is launched with this environment variable set to a location inside my project's path (`lib/linux-x86-64`).

I figure that all I really need to do is make sure that `bashScriptExtraDefines` add an entry of `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$lib_dir/linux-x86-64`, however I cannot seem to figure out the correct way of setting it. I believe this is an issue with SBT 0.13 not being able to see these settings until they have all compiled, but there must be *some* way to do so.

I tried simply doing the following in my .sbt file:

```
bashScriptExtraDefines += "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$lib_dir/linux-x86-64"
```

and I tried changing my Project's settings in Build.scala file in the following way:

```
lazy val root = Project("my-project",file("."),Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(bashScriptExtraDefines += "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$lib_dir/linux-x86-64"))
```

Neither method works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I learned that this setting can't be accessed in the regular scope since it seems to be limited to the Plugin's scope. The way to get around this is by accessing it out of the NativePackagerKeys object that the plugin exports. The following works inside my sbt file:

```
NativePackagerKeys.bashScriptExtraDefines += "export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$lib_dir/linux-x86-64"
```